# WordPress add category in menu

Tags: php, wordpress

In my website in menu bar I have 4 static menu items and one needs to be dynamic. Like

```
Home | About us | contact us| Services| Product
```

In this menu item list. I want "product" category along with its subcategories as sub menu. shown in menu. Like

```
Product
 - sub product 1
     - sub product 1.1
 - sub product 2
 - sub product 3
     - sub product 3.1
```

Please suggest me how to fulfill above requirement.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `wp_list_categories()` to create a `<ul><li>` list of all your categories and style that with CSS to get a menu.  More info on `wp_list_categories()` here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories (see the list of arguments).

Answer (score 2):

Make use of WordPress Menus, it helps you add Categories, Pages & Custom Links. WordPress Menus can also act as a dynamic menu if you check *Automatically add new top-level pages* option while creating it.

Reference: [Add Multiple Menus in WordPress](http://www.thecreatology.com/multiple-navigation-menus-using-wordpress-menu-3-0-with-thesis-theme.html)

Answer (score 1):

To add menu goto admin panel. In left Side bat click on Appearance then on menus.
From there you can add menus and sud menus. For submenu drag link under main menu. 
You can also add custom links from here.

Comment: Yes, but Product menu should contain all the items as sub menu which are sub-categories of product category.

Comment: I guess Arya wants this to be dynamic. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: or use <?php wp_list_categories ('sort_column=menu_order&title_li'); ?>